# Multiple consecutive .* in expression lead to slow matching

Tags: regex, java-7

I noticed that if I use the regular expression
`.*.*text.*.*`, the matching takes substantially longer than when matching on `.*text.*`

As you may have guessed the regular expression with the double `.*.*` is (accidentally) generated by software.

So 2 questions follow:

1. I am planning to replace `.*.*` with `.*` before running the matching. Can I always replace `.*.*` with `.*`? Is there any scenario whereby `.*.*` does not functionally equal `.*` in a regular expression?
2. Can anyone explain in a simple way why it takes that much longer to match the `.*.*`?

And in case this is an implementation specific behaviour, I am using Java 7's regular expression engine.

Comment: Yes, you can.  always a, possible empty, sequence of characters can be divided into two sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In term of matches `.*.*` is **equivalent** to `.*`. In term of performance, you'll save a lot of time. You should learn about backtracking.

You can see the step number between [`.*.*Donec.*.*`](https://regex101.com/r/CvwXNo/1) and [`.*Donec.*`](https://regex101.com/r/CvwXNo/2) goes from **101 897** to only **604** against the two first paragraphs of the Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: In fact, a pattern like this is just begging for [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz it depends of the length of the input and the implementations

Comment: I agree, but it might be worth mentioning. I've created [an amended version of yours](https://regex101.com/r/CvwXNo/3) that demonstrates this effect (same pattern, altered text).

Comment: Thanks all! Makes sense now! Since I am creating regular expressions based on user input, I concluded (with your help) that i MUST replace all consecutive `.*` to a single `.*`. Is there any other sanitization that is good practice to do to the user's input?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz If you want to showcase catastraophic backtracking, you almost always better use a failing (depending on the given regex partial matching) sample

Answer (score 0):

The two regex `.*` and `.*.*` are absolutely equal in mathematical terms.  If they don't match at the same speed is due to the implementation used on compiling and matching.

If you use a good regex compiler, you'll get a one pass, no backtracking algorithm that explores each character of the matched string only once, dealing to a `O[n]` algorithm, independent of the complexity of the regular expression you use.

By the way, all the curren implementations used in the vast majority of languages (perl, java, php, etc.) derive from the direct interpretation of the finite NFA (Nondeterministic Finite Automata) over the matcher string.  But if you read algorithms like the one described in [Compilers, Principles, Techniques and Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) you'll find that you can get the match in only one visit to each character (and in sequence)